# Upper bound for a probability of sum of random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Edit:
Is it possible to give an upper bound for the probability $\mathbb{P}(\left(X+Y\right)^{2}-\mu_{Y^{2}}\leq \delta)$ in terms of $P(X^2\leq c_{1}(\delta))$, $P(Y^2\leq c_{2}(\delta))$ and, if necessary the mixed term? Fruthermore, we can assume, that $X$ and $Y$ are independent.
It would be great to get an upper bound, such that I could apply Markov inequality applied to the function $\varphi(x)=x^{r}$ for some positive $r$.

Comment: I would be surprised if you could find this bound without making any assumptions about how $X, Y$ and $Z$ are related. For any (a.s finite) random variable $X$, if $Y=Z=-\frac{1}{2}X$ then for any positive $\delta$, 
$$
P(|X+Y+Z|\le \delta)=P(0\le \delta) = 1
$$

Comment: @1524
You are right. I have edited the question.

Comment: Is $\mu_Y$ the expectation of $Y$? Note that if $\delta + \mu_Y < 0$ the probabilty is always zero since the squared sum of $X$ and $Y$ is non-negative.

Are you sure you're looking for an upper bound and not a lower one?

Comment: Yes, but, I meant $\mu_{Y^{2}}$ instead of $\mu_{Y}$. I have added some further information.